# SQL Server displaying query output in certain format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Question:**

How can I display the student name, the department name and the course name of every course that the student has not taken?

I have tried using generating a cartesian product like this:

```
SELECT  
    NAME, student.dept_name, title
FROM 
    student
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         id, title
     FROM 
         takes, course
     WHERE 
         takes.course_id <> course.course_id) a ON student.id = a.id
ORDER BY 
    NAME ASC, title ASC
```

And it works fine as long as the student only takes 1 course, but not if he attends to more than one

Can you guys provide a solution ? Thanks in advance

[Database relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zbjx.png)

The desired output is a connection of the values in this format

```
| name | dept_name | title (course name) |
```

Comment: Kindly share schema and desired output.

Comment: I've put the schema and the desired output :)

Comment: Your query is NOT a Cartesian product (which is a `CROSS JOIN`)

Comment: Logically the cartesian product/ cross join should be on student to courses.

Comment: Please use ansi join syntax. That is what they should learn you in school, not the old scool way

Comment: the problem is there is no connection between student and courses. what should i do ?

Comment: Why is the join between course and takes a not equals. If a student takes 3 courses and their are 6 courses in the table your result is 3*5 thus 15 rows.

Comment: @AbBennett yeah i want to display the course that the student doesn't take. if i make it equals then it will shows the courses that the student takes.

Comment: Yes but doin not equals won’t work either I’ll do answer below

Comment: Are there columns not displayed in that (huge) image? table [takes] seems to be missing student_id

Comment: @Used_By_Already ID refers to student_id

Comment: @AbBennett yeah I'm just writing anything comes to my head haha

Comment: ok, but that is a poor naming convention.... [takes] should have its own unique id, and the reference to student should be [student_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a query that gets all combos of student and courses by doing Cartesian join, then remove all the courses a student has done by doing the 2nd query below the except. This handles a student who has not done any courses yet, which is why a not exists doesn’t work.

```
Select s.id, c.title 
From student s cross join courses c
Except
Select t.id, c.title 
From takes t join courses c on t.course_id = c.course_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there is no connection between courses an student is not an issue you need to know all the courses a student could take so given

student

```
Name       CourseId
---------- ----------
Zishan     1,2,3
Ellen      2,3,4

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Course

```
courseid    coursename
----------- ----------
1           java
2           C++
3           oracle
4           dot net
```

Courses_taken

```
sid                  cid
-------------------- -----------
zishan               1
zishan               2

(2 row(s) affected)
```

a cross join like this

```
select s.Name Studentname, c.courseid cid,c.coursename CourseNAme
from student s
cross join course c
```

Results in

```
Studentname cid         CourseNAme
----------- ----------- ----------
Zishan      1           java
Zishan      2           C++
Zishan      3           oracle
Zishan      4           dot net
Ellen       1           java
Ellen       2           C++
Ellen       3           oracle
Ellen       4           dot net
```

Joining to courses_taken

```
select sc.Studentname,sc.Coursename,ct.cid
from
(
select s.Name Studentname, c.courseid cid,c.coursename CourseNAme
from student s
cross join course c
) sc
left join courses_taken  ct on sc.StudentName = ct.sid and sc.cid = ct.cid
```

results in this

```
Studentname Coursename cid
----------- ---------- -----------
Zishan      java       1
Zishan      C++        2
Zishan      oracle     NULL
Zishan      dot net    NULL
Ellen       java       NULL
Ellen       C++        NULL
Ellen       oracle     NULL
Ellen       dot net    NULL
```

To exclude the courses taken a null where condition

```
select sc.Studentname,sc.Coursename,ct.cid
from
(
select s.Name Studentname, c.courseid cid,c.coursename CourseNAme
from student s
cross join course c
) sc
left join courses_taken  ct on sc.StudentName = ct.sid and sc.cid = ct.cid
where ct.cid is null
```

Results in

```
Studentname Coursename cid
----------- ---------- -----------
Zishan      oracle     NULL
Zishan      dot net    NULL
Ellen       java       NULL
Ellen       C++        NULL
Ellen       oracle     NULL
Ellen       dot net    NULL

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    s.*, c.*
from students s
cross join courses c
left join takes t on s.student_id = t.id -- naming looks weird
                 and c.course_id = t.course_id
where t.student_id IS NULL
order by
  s.name, c.title -- or similar
```

A `cross join` forms a `Cartesian product` that forms all combinations of student + course. Outer join that large potential set to the actual set of students enrolled to courses. Then, the un-joined rows constitute the courses that have not been taken by (each) student.

If the questions has a small "twist" and that all you need is the list of un-taken courses then:

```
select distinct
    c.*
from students s
cross join courses c
left join takes t on s.student_id = t.id -- naming looks weird
                 and c.course_id = t.course_id
where t.student_id IS NULL
order by
  c.title -- or similar
```

Will simplify the result to just the untaken courses.